# How to Extract tar.xz with password on Google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tar, xz

I have a tar.xz file.

So far I have seen many file extractions but not with tar.xz files with passwords.

Please, thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by tar.xz files with passwords? Unless the extension is wrong, a tar.xz file is an archive (tar) compressed with xz: there is no password involved at any point.

Answer (score 0):

The [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) command is not like **zip**.

There is no option for defining/using a password to protect the contents.

"**xz**" is only a suffix to identify the compression scheme added after the tar file was created.